# Creating an IQueryable to Equal int32?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iqueryable

I am trying to create an query extension which would compare a nullable int sql column value with a value. But i am struggling already over 8 hours to find any working solution.

I have already found a lot of help on this side. But all the remarks did not helped me.

I have altered the code so many times, but nothing seems to work. I want to create something similar as WHERE ManagerID IN (10,20,30)

The main code

```
IQueryable<Users> query = _context.CreateObjectSet<Users>();
query = query.IsMember(a => a.ManagerID, new Int32?[] { 10,20,30 });
return query.ToList();
```

Currently while executing the query.ToList(); it returns me a

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

```
public static IQueryable<T> IsMember<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, Int32?>> stringProperty, params Int32?[] searchTerms)
    {
        if (searchTerms == null || !searchTerms.Any())
        {
            return source;
        }

        Expression orExpression = null;
        foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
        {
            var searchTermExpression = Expression.Constant(searchTerm, typeof(object)); // <<--- This cast would make it no longer a primitive type

            var containsExpression = Expression.Call(stringProperty.Body, typeof(Int32?).GetMethod("Equals"), searchTermExpression);

            orExpression = BuildOrExpression(orExpression, containsExpression);
        }

        var completeExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, stringProperty.Parameters);
        return source.Where(completeExpression);
    }

    private static Expression BuildOrExpression(Expression existingExpression, Expression expressionToAdd)
    {
        return existingExpression == null ? expressionToAdd : Expression.OrElse(existingExpression, expressionToAdd);
    }
```

The line marked to give the constant another datatype, is indeed causing the issue, but if I dont make it of type object, the Expression will not work, as it could not match the Int32? datatype.

Can anybody help me?

thanks

=============================================

## Additional info

It is indeed to had a a larger picture.
I just want to create something more dynamic which could be used on other projects also.

I would like to use some functions which will look appealing than all those multilines

```
query = query.Like(a => a.UserName, filter.UserName, true);
query = query.Equals(a => a.UserTown, filter.UserTown, true);
query = query.IsMember(a => a.Division, filter.Division); // is an array of possible divisions
```

it worked fine for Like and Equals which are string based. But want to have a similar product for (nullable) integers

I was inspired by the following post. Which created a search function (which i renamed for my project to Like)
[link](http://jnye.co/Posts/6/c%23-generic-search-extension-method-for-iqueryable)

I wanted to create others similar. the last boolean is to verify if nullable in the column is allowed or not.

The reason also to use an extension, is that i also have alot of filters in my filter page. 
With this extension, i would easily check in the beginning of my Like and Equal function if a filter was given without checking if my filter has a value 20x.

```
public static IQueryable<T> Like<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> stringProperty, string searchTerm, bool isnullValueAllowed)
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            return query;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just use this `query.Where(a => (new Int32?[] { 10,20,30 }).Contains(a.ManagerID)` ? .. just asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to create this extension as you could simply write something like:

```cs
query.Where(user => (new[]{10,20,30}).Contains(user.ManagerId)).ToList();
```

However, assuming the real use case is somewhat more complicated than the example you've given, could you not construct your expression as either a comparison against a constant Int32 or a comparison against null, depending on whether `searchTerm.HasValue()` was true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the equality operator `==` rather than the `Equals` method here.  It actually makes your expression code a tad simpler:

```
foreach (var searchTerm in searchTerms)
{
    var comparison = Expression.Equals(stringProperty.Body, 
        Expression.Constant(searchTerm));

    orExpression = BuildOrExpression(orExpression, comparison);
}
```

Of course, as is mentioned by others, you don't need to build up an expression representing an OR of each of these comparisons, you can simply use `Conatains` on the set in a lambda and the query provider will do all of this for you.

Comment: I found that Int32? does not have the Equal function embedded. Would it be possible to create an extension which will be handled as similar as the string.Equal ?

Comment: @Cedric Sure it would.